# Removing the Item from the dropdown once its added using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTML Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>
    document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1> NG options</h1>
  <form name="addUser">
    Application:
    <select ng-model="filterAddUser.application" ng-init ="filterAddUser.application = 'STACK'" title="" ng-options="value as value for  (key , value) in applicationStatus">
    </select>
    Roles:
    <select ng-model="filterAddUser.role" title="" ng-init ="filterAddUser.role = 'R'" ng-options="role.value as role.param for role in roleStatus">
    </select>

    <button ng-click="addToCart()">AddItem</button>

    <div class="addCart">
      <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
        <li><b>Application:</b> {{item.application}}</li>
        <li><b>Role:</b> {{item.role}}</li>
        <li class="actionOptions">
          <button ng-click="toggleSelected($index)">removeItem</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript Code

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [];

  $scope.applicationStatus = {
    "TEST App": "TEST",
    "ABC App": "ABC",
    "TRY App": "TRY",
    "SIR App": "SIR",
    "LOPR App": "LOPR",
    "STACK App": "STACK"
  };
  $scope.roleStatus = [{
    "param": "Read",
    "value": "R"
  }, {
    "param": "Write",
    "value": "W"
  }, {
    "param": "Admin",
    "value": "A"
  }, {
    "param": "Super Approver",
    "value": "SA"
  }, {
    "param": "Supervisor",
    "value": "S"
  }];


  $scope.addToCart = function() {

    $scope.items.push({
      application: $scope.filterAddUser.application,
      role: $scope.filterAddUser.role
    });
    // Clear input fields after push
    $scope.filterAddUser['application'] = "";
    $scope.filterAddUser['role'] = "";
  }

  $scope.toggleSelected = function(index) {
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
  };

});
```

All that i am trying to do is when i add the application to the cart that application needs to be removed from the dropdwon and also when i click on the remove item that needs to be pushed back to the cart i have included a plunker as well http://plnkr.co/edit/kSsetX?p=preview
need help on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated your plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/QQobh7Jx76r7lDzw7TzV

```
       var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];
  var deletedApplication = [];

  $scope.applicationStatus = {
    "TEST App": "TEST",
    "ABC App": "ABC",
    "TRY App": "TRY",
    "SIR App": "SIR",
    "LOPR App": "LOPR",
    "STACK App": "STACK"
  };

  $scope.roleStatus = [{
    "param": "Read",
    "value": "R"
  }, {
    "param": "Write",
    "value": "W"
  }, {
    "param": "Admin",
    "value": "A"
  }, {
    "param": "Super Approver",
    "value": "SA"
  }, {
    "param": "Supervisor",
    "value": "S"
  }];

  $scope.filterAddUser = {
    application: $scope.applicationStatus[0],
    role: $scope.roleStatus[0]
  };


  $scope.addToCart = function() {
    deletedApplication.push([
      $scope.filterAddUser.application,  $scope.applicationStatus[$scope.filterAddUser.application]
    ]);

    delete $scope.applicationStatus[$scope.filterAddUser.application];

    $scope.items.push({
      application: $scope.filterAddUser.application,
      role: $scope.filterAddUser.role
    });

    // Clear input fields after push
    $scope.filterAddUser['application'] = $scope.applicationStatus[0];
    $scope.filterAddUser['role'] = $scope.roleStatus[0];

  }

  $scope.toggleSelected = function(index) {
    var addApp = deletedApplication.filter(function(deletedApp){
      return deletedApp[0] === $scope.items[index].application;
    })[0];

    $scope.applicationStatus[addApp[0]] = addApp[1];  
    console.log($scope.applicationStatus);
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
  };

});
```

Comment: I will update your plunkr and update my answer in a minute. Also I just noticed your plunkr is using different code than you posted, thats where my confusion is!

Comment: This code should give you an idea of where to go with it. Let me know if you need more help with it.

Comment: Updated again. Let me know if that works for you. It was a little tricky because applicationStatus was an object. Plunkr is updated as well as code in answer

Comment: Thanks Kevin that was precisicely what i was looking for and i appreciate your help i am novice can u help me in improving my skills i was stuck with this issue for three days:(

Comment: No problem! I've been using angular for a few years now and it took me awhile to figure out as well so don't be too discouraged. Iterating over object keys like an array is never fun

Comment: No one could even increase your skills. You are the one who only can. Come SO regularly, read the latest Q&A and ask your query if you have. Don't worry about anything. It'd be our pleasure to dig more with you in code.

Comment: i am sorry to ask you the same thing again i just made a small change in the ngoptions instead of reading key as value i wanted value as value and it broke the whole logic i am not able to fix it now :( any help pls

Comment: Can you update and post the plunkr with your new logic and I will take a look?

Comment: Updated Plunker Link http://plnkr.co/edit/9SzzNs?p=preview Thanks in advance waiting for your response!!

Comment: @KevinF can you help me in this other question if you get some time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30598614/creating-a-valid-server-response-from-javascript-angular