# Creating a valid server response from javascript/Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

My JSON

```
{
    "RECORDS": [
        {
            "Id": 23040035705987,
            "arriveddate": "2015/04/24",
            "expirationDate": null,
            "replacedDate": null,
            "processDate": "2015/04/24"
        },        
        {
            "Id": 23070041800654,
            "arriveddate": "2015/04/24",
            "expirationDate": null,
            "replacedDate": null,
            "processDate": "2015/04/27"
        },
                {
            "Id": 23040035705984,
            "arriveddate": "2015/04/24",
            "expirationDate": null,
            "replacedDate": null,
            "processDate": "2015/04/24"
        },
                {
            "Id": 23040035705983,
            "arriveddate": "2015/04/24",
            "expirationDate": null,
            "replacedDate": null,
            "processDate": "2015/04/24"
        }
    ],
}
```

Expected Object

```
    {
    "processDate": [
        "2015/04/24",
        "2015/04/27"
    ],
    "Id": [
        [
            23040035705983,
            23040035705984,
            23040035705987
        ],
        [
            23070041800654
        ]
    ]
}
```

i need to do a mapping based on the process date like in my expected object i have two dates which are the unique dates of all my JSON and in the next ids i have each id which belongs to that corresponding process dates right now i have been able to get the unique process dates but in the next ids i am not able to do can you please provide an example as to how i should loop through to achieve the same in angular

Answer (score 0):

You could use two nested forEach loops.

```
angular.forEach(obj.processDate, function(processValue, processIndex,date) {
  angular.forEach(obj2.RECORDS, function (recordValue, recordIndex,records) {
    if (processValue === recordValue["processDate"]) {
      if (!obj["Id"][processIndex]) {
        obj["Id"][processIndex]=[];
      }
      obj["Id"][processIndex].push(recordValue["Id"]);
    });
   });
 }
```